# Stuck in Room in the Upper City

Tags: prince-of-persia-the-lost-crown

Does anyone know how to get out of this room without:

> Chakram Teleport

I don't have this skill yet.

Here where I'm at on the map:

[image]

I've exited to the main menu, and when going back in takes me back to this room. My cloud save has already updated - so, no restoring here.

I've attempted wall jumping and it's impossible.

Am I just stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there is a way to jump out. I recorded it and posted a video on how to do this. It took almost 50 tries for me to get this, but it is possible:

[How to Escape Room](https://youtu.be/Pu_KprsK0ME)